# $wp_query when new WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, search, hooks

I'm trying something but I have an issue with WP_Query.

I've an Hook on the_post in order to add some variation on the query.

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'query_variation');

function query_variation($posts, $query = false) {
    if (is_search())
    {
    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

It's working well when I'm searching on the site. But, I know creating an ajax search like that :

```
function ajax_search_123( ){
     $search_keyword = esc_attr($_REQUEST['query']);
     $args = array(
            's'                     => $search_keyword),
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'posts_per_page'        => 3,
        );
        $products_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // Do stuff with $product_query
}
```

But when I instanciate WP_Query with $args, is_search() doesn't return true so I'm entering on the if...

What Can I do ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It's hard to know without more context, but it sounds like you may be better served by the [`pre_get_posts` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are slightly confusing `$wp_query` global variable with `WP_Query` class/objects. `$wp_query` is an object instance of `WP_Query`, but not every `WP_Query` object has anything to do with `$wp_query` global.

Function version of conditionals, such as `is_search()`, always act on main global query. You shouldn't use them inside filters, since global state might be one thing and the query you are actually in another.

Inside hooks you should be always making checks on instance of query provided, via its methods. For example `$query->is_search()`.

Comment: Understood, so I can't use get_search_query() but $query->get('s') instead ?

Comment: @XcID yes, and so on. Just check sources of the "global" versions of function to see which data they are wrapping and how.